# Dynamically generate multiple RadioButtonList and capture their values

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, dynamic

I have a situation where I need to generate multiple sets of radio buttons. These radio buttons display One to Many relationship data.

I know how to get it to work with a workaround that I used back in Classic ASP days ... in which I essentially just spit out the HTML dynamically and keep track of my controls using systematic IDs. Which is nothing more then an Primary Key appended to a string constant i.e. `String.Format("Dynamic_{0}", myChildRecordPKValue)` so my HTML looks like this:

```
<!--First Group-->
<h1>Parent Record 1</h1>
<input id="Child_998" name="group_1" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>First
<input id="Child_999" name="group_1" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>Second
<input id="Child_1000" name="group_1" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>Third

<!--Second Group-->
<h1>Parent Record 2</h1>
<input id="Child_4598" name="group_2" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>First
<input id="Child_7632" name="group_2" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>Second
<input id="Child_92" name="group_2" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>Third

<!--Second Group-->
<h1>Parent Record 3</h1>
<input id="Child_556" name="group_3" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>First
<input id="Child_786" name="group_3" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>Second
<input id="Child_110" name="group_3" onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"/>Third
```

Note that I am using a javascript function which updates a hidden field with the selected value (Each parent record has a corresponding hidden field). So after making selection user will hit the submit button and I get my values using Request.Form[myHiddenField1] and so on ...

So, my question is ... is there a better "ASP.NET" way of solving this problem?

Comment: In Page_Init, so that it's there before you start to do databinding

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit, plz?

Comment: If you want to get to them on postback they have to exist when the viewstate is unloaded from the postback data into the page, so you have to create the elements before then. Doing it in or after page_load does not create them early enough in the page lifecycle. Create them in Page_Init

Comment: Let me know if you need more help, also, using @ in front of the name, like so @robert, will get you a response much faster on SO ... welcome to the community

Answer (score 0):

I would look at creating a composite server control.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)